# camel IllegalStateException: Queue full

Tags: queue, apache-camel

I have a route with a size set to 5000 like so:

```
    <route id="rdfProcessContent">
        <from uri="vm:rdfProcessContent?concurrentConsumers=2&size=5000&blockWhenFull=true"/>
        .........
    </route>
```

One question- 5000 size, is it too much or can I do something much higher? Or is there something else that I could do? Also, I'm using a try/catch (below), but is it a good way of dealing with a full queue?
If it matters, the route gets accessed in the following way:

```
def endPoint = camelContext.getEndpoint("vm:rdfProcessContent?size=5000");
def producer = endPoint.createProducer();
.... 
try{
    while(gotNextPage)
    {
        ...
        contentList.each{
            ...
            def exchange = endPoint.createExchange(org.apache.camel.ExchangePattern.InOnly);
            exchange.getIn().setBody(it);
            exchange.getIn().setHeader("isBulkLoad", "true" );  
            producer.process(exchange);                     
        }
    }
}catch(){...}
```

Here is the error I'm getting (first bit of the error):

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Queue full
at java.util.AbstractQueue.add(AbstractQueue.java:71)
at org.apache.camel.component.seda.SedaProducer.addToQueue(SedaProducer.java:233)
at org.apache.camel.component.seda.SedaProducer.process(SedaProducer.java:170)
at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:113)
at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:72)
at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:398)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
at org.apache.camel.processor.FilterProcessor.process(FilterProcessor.java:58)
at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:72)
at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:398)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:105)
```

Thank you for taking the time.

Comment: What is your question? Yes you can see the queue size higher if you want, just mind the queue is in-memory based so it requires memory to use, and also the messages are not persistent, so they disappear if the JVM crashes.

Comment: I tried 20000 for the  size, and I tried also increasing and decreasing concurrentConsumers, but the queue fills up in about 5 min to 2 hours. I seem to unable to get the setting right. It seems that something is amiss.

Comment: You can throttle on the producer side, with blockWhenFull=true. And of course it will fill up you have an endless while loop.

Comment: The blockWhenfull is already in place.

Comment: No you need to set it on the producer side, you have it on the wrong side

Answer (score 0):

After digging around, I found that the issue was NOT with route "rdfProcessContent", but a route farther in execution - I was using JAVA api to post graphs. That turned out to be much slower than posting sparql queries - a big surprise.